# Excel create a series of same values?

Tags: excel

I wonder if there is a way to make calculating IRR simpler? For example, I have a steady income of $500/month, and I want to see the IRR for 6 months, 12 months, 18 months, etc.

Currently, I have to create three columns, one with 6 rows of $500, one with 12 rows of $500, etc.

Is there a way to sissified the calculation?

P.S. There is actually a different last payment value, so I cannot create a 12 rows and pick subset of the same values.

Comment: Have you had a look at `XIRR` formula?

Comment: @assylias Yes, I have looked at XIRR formula, but I think RATE function is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED** 
After reading lori-m 's comment, I have added more to my reply to illustrate RATE calculation as performed internally by Excel RATE function

---

### Original Reply

I assume that the last value is a negative amount, as you will need at least one negative amount to find [IRR](http://finance.thinkanddone.com/irr.html).

When the annuity payments are in constant amounts, you can opt to use [Excel RATE function](http://thinkanddone.co.uk/en-gb/excel_rate_calculator.html) to calculate internal rate of return

RATE function accepts the following values

=RATE(NPER, PMT, PV, [FV], type)

NPER will be the number of periods in your case 6, 12, 18

PMT is the periodic payment in this case 500

PV is the present worth of annuity if it is an outgoing cash flow then you need to specify this as a negative amount

FV is the salvage value

Using of RATE function requires that at least one or at most two of the following values must be negative FV, PV, or PMT

Yet reading from what you wrote you may not even have negative cash flow thus rendering it impossible to use either IRR or RATE functions

---

### The following text shows how RATE function calculates internal rate of return or simply a rate of return using the [TVM equations](http://finance.thinkanddone.com/finding_irr_with_tvm_equation_using_newton_raphson_method.html)

```
Newton Raphson Method IRR Calculation with TVM equation = 0

TVM Eq. 1: PV(1+i)^N + PMT(1+i*type)[(1+i)^N -1]/i + FV = 0

f(i) = 0 + 500 * (1 + i * 0) [(1+i)^6 - 1)]/i + -2500 * (1+i)^6

f'(i) = (500 * ( 6 * i * (1 + i)^(5+0) - (1 + i)^6) + 1) / (i * i)) + 6 * -2500 * (1+0.1)^5

i0 = 0.1
f(i1) = -571.0975
f'(i1) = -14420.4
i1 = 0.1 - -571.0975/-14420.4 = 0.0603965562675
Error Bound = 0.0603965562675 - 0.1 = 0.039603 > 0.000001

i1 = 0.0603965562675
f(i2) = -63.1212
f'(i2) = -11318.2776
i2 = 0.0603965562675 - -63.1212/-11318.2776 = 0.0548196309075
Error Bound = 0.0548196309075 - 0.0603965562675 = 0.005577 > 0.000001

i2 = 0.0548196309075
f(i3) = -1.1104
f'(i3) = -10921.6385
i3 = 0.0548196309075 - -1.1104/-10921.6385 = 0.0547179582964
Error Bound = 0.0547179582964 - 0.0548196309075 = 0.000102 > 0.000001

i3 = 0.0547179582964
f(i4) = -0.0004
f'(i4) = -10914.4953
i4 = 0.0547179582964 - -0.0004/-10914.4953 = 0.0547179250235
Error Bound = 0.0547179250235 - 0.0547179582964 = 0 < 0.000001
IRR = 5.47%


Newton Raphson Method IRR Calculation with TVM equation = 0

TVM Eq. 2: PV + PMT(1+i*type)[1-{(1+i)^-N}]/i + FV(1+i)^-N = 0

f(i) = -2500 + 500 * (1 + i * 0) [1 - (1+i)^-6)]/i + 0 * (1+i)^-6

f'(i) = (-500 * (1+i)^-6 * ((1+i)^6 - 6 * i - 1) /(i*i)) + (0 * -6 * (1+i)^(-6-1))

i0 = 0.1
f(i1) = -322.3697
f'(i1) = -4842.0856
i1 = 0.1 - -322.3697/-4842.0856 = 0.0334233887655
Error Bound = 0.0334233887655 - 0.1 = 0.066577 > 0.000001

i1 = 0.0334233887655
f(i2) = 178.1297
f'(i2) = -6438.6863
i2 = 0.0334233887655 - 178.1297/-6438.6863 = 0.0610889228796
Error Bound = 0.0610889228796 - 0.0334233887655 = 0.027666 > 0.000001

i2 = 0.0610889228796
f(i3) = -49.7272
f'(i3) = -5702.834
i3 = 0.0610889228796 - -49.7272/-5702.834 = 0.0523691914645
Error Bound = 0.0523691914645 - 0.0610889228796 = 0.00872 > 0.000001

i3 = 0.0523691914645
f(i4) = 18.7303
f'(i4) = -5922.4426
i4 = 0.0523691914645 - 18.7303/-5922.4426 = 0.055531790412
Error Bound = 0.055531790412 - 0.0523691914645 = 0.003163 > 0.000001

i4 = 0.055531790412
f(i5) = -6.4397
f'(i5) = -5841.5461
i5 = 0.055531790412 - -6.4397/-5841.5461 = 0.054429394433
Error Bound = 0.054429394433 - 0.055531790412 = 0.001102 > 0.000001

i5 = 0.054429394433
f(i6) = 2.2892
f'(i6) = -5869.581
i6 = 0.054429394433 - 2.2892/-5869.581 = 0.0548194083235
Error Bound = 0.0548194083235 - 0.054429394433 = 0.00039 > 0.000001

i6 = 0.0548194083235
f(i7) = -0.8044
f'(i7) = -5859.6427
i7 = 0.0548194083235 - -0.8044/-5859.6427 = 0.0546821305725
Error Bound = 0.0546821305725 - 0.0548194083235 = 0.000137 > 0.000001

i7 = 0.0546821305725
f(i8) = 0.2838
f'(i8) = -5863.1383
i8 = 0.0546821305725 - 0.2838/-5863.1383 = 0.0547305377303
Error Bound = 0.0547305377303 - 0.0546821305725 = 4.8E-5 > 0.000001

i8 = 0.0547305377303
f(i9) = -0.1
f'(i9) = -5861.9054
i9 = 0.0547305377303 - -0.1/-5861.9054 = 0.0547134792018
Error Bound = 0.0547134792018 - 0.0547305377303 = 1.7E-5 > 0.000001

i9 = 0.0547134792018
f(i10) = 0.0352
f'(i10) = -5862.3398
i10 = 0.0547134792018 - 0.0352/-5862.3398 = 0.054719491928
Error Bound = 0.054719491928 - 0.0547134792018 = 6.0E-6 > 0.000001

i10 = 0.054719491928
f(i11) = -0.0124
f'(i11) = -5862.1867
i11 = 0.054719491928 - -0.0124/-5862.1867 = 0.0547173727531
Error Bound = 0.0547173727531 - 0.054719491928 = 2.0E-6 > 0.000001

i11 = 0.0547173727531
f(i12) = 0.0044
f'(i12) = -5862.2407
i12 = 0.0547173727531 - 0.0044/-5862.2407 = 0.0547181196735
Error Bound = 0.0547181196735 - 0.0547173727531 = 1.0E-6 < 0.000001
IRR = 5.47%
```

Comment: +1: use RATE. eg `=IRR({-2500,500,500,500,500,500,500})` and `=RATE(6,500,-2500)` both return the same value of 5.47% which is the monthly discount rate at which six months salary $500/month nets out to a $2500 initial payment i.e. `474.06+449.47+426.15+404.04+383.08+363.21=2500`.

Comment: Thanks! RATE function looks exactly what I'm after.